# Do I need to do something about "Delta RPMs disabled"?

Tags: centos, rpm

While updating packages on our CentOS server I got the following message:

```
Downloading packages:
Delta RPMs disabled because /usr/bin/applydeltarpm not installed.
```

Do I need to do something about that? Should I just ignore this?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You don't need to do something, but you can, especially if you have a slow internet connection. If you install deltarpm support:

```
yum install deltarpm
```

you will download only the differences with older versions of already installed packages. This is done at the cost of increased processing time.