# What is DRPM and How does it differ from RPM?

Tags: centos, rpm

Doing an update on my CentOS 7 box and I noticed that there was a handful of DRPMs being installed. After doing some searches on google, there is no straight up Answer for this question so I thought it would fit here to ask.

- I am wondering what is a DRPM?
- How does it differ from a RPM package?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A `drpm` stands for `delta rpm`, which is an addition to an existing `rpm`, and only contains the different files. [Source](https://www.pks.mpg.de/~mueller/docs/suse10.2/html/opensuse-manual_en/manual/sec.rpm.delta.html):

> Delta RPM packages contain the difference between an old and a new
>   version of an RPM package. Applying a delta RPM on an old RPM results
>   in the complete new RPM. It is not necessary to have a copy of the old
>   RPM, because a delta RPM can also work with an installed RPM. The
>   delta RPM packages are even smaller in size than patch RPMs, which is
>   an advantage when transferring update packages over the Internet. The
>   drawback is that update operations with delta RPMs involved consume
>   considerably more CPU cycles than plain or patch RPMs.

The README file referred to in the documentation can be found in the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/rpm-software-management/deltarpm/blob/master/README). You will see that `deltarpm` is based on `bsdiff`.

Answer (score 9):

DRPM files are Delta RPM files.  They do not contain a complete package but only the difference (= delta) between two (RPM) packages.  This is useful for faster download and installation of RPM files that are an upgrade to an existing (installed) package.  Only new and changed files need to be included here.

In order for `yum` to work with drpm files you need to install the `deltarpm` package:

```
yum install deltarpm
```

This contains the necessary tool.

See also [Do I need to do something about "Delta RPMs disabled"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/277900/do-i-need-to-do-something-about-delta-rpms-disabled)

Answer (score 5):

DRPMS: Instead of downloading full packages for minor changes , delta rpms were invented. As far as I know from Suse linux first.
Only changes between the installed package and the new one are downloaded. Once the delta rpm loaded, a rebuilding process is started. At the end, the reconstructed RPM is put into yum download directory, where the normal package installation routines pick it up and install it.