# How do delta RPMs work at the server end?

Tags: rhel, rpm, packaging

Here's a question and answers on what delta RPMs actually are: [What is DRPM and How does it differ from RPM?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/368867/what-is-drpm-and-how-does-it-differ-from-rpm/368872#368872)

I'm interested in the algorithms and data structures server side. I've Googled but nothing useful shows up.

Do they (Red Hat) generate the requested delta on the fly, or are all possible deltas pregenerated and made available as soon as a new RPM comes out?

Comment: Other than `makedeltarpm`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deltas are generated when repo is created/updated. Usually:

```
createrepo_c --update --deltas --num-deltas 1 .
```

For more information see `man createrepo_c` and `man makedeltarpm`

Comment: This answer really doesn't go too much in details especially about the second part of the question "are all possible deltas pregenerated and made available as soon as a new RPM comes out?".